# Can I look up an EJB via JNDI and invoke methods using reflection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I'm using EJB 3.1. I need to get a references to one of the EJBs in a servlet and I'd rather not put an EJB interface jar on the class path to get the code to compile.

Is it possible to look an EJB via JNDI and find the method I want to invoke using reflection without ever strongly typing the object to an interface?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're looking up a local EJB interface, then you can look up and invoke a local EJB within the same application using reflection.

This should work if you're using a direct lookup or an EJB ref lookup because the Java EE spec requires the application server to make EJB module classes available to WARs within the same application.  The EJB spec doesn't require support for local interfaces across applications, so if that's what you're doing, you'll have to check with your application server vendor.

This will not work in general for remote EJB interfaces because a client proxy needs to be created.  If you're using RMI-IIOP (EJB 2.x remote or EJB 3 extending java.rmi.Remote), you might be able to cast the EJB lookup result to javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub and use the _servant_preinvoke or _invoke methods the same as a generated stub method would do.

(Ultimately, this is a lot of caveats just to avoid a compile-time dependency.  It's probably not worth the fragility, so I would recommend finding a way to solve that and compile normally.)